# How to delete "Just" in Maybe String or Maybe Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i am new to haskell and in need of a little help with a problem. I have a XML file and i want to parse two things in it. One is a pair of numbers, and the second is just a letter. I use two functions to parse each element, and the result of that functions has to be "Maybe String", or else it won't work.

The problem is, that when i display the result it allways has a "Just" attached to it. So if i want to display something like **(1,2)** and **B**

I will have **(Just "1", Just "2")** and **Just "B"**

For the numbers i got the solution. I have made this function to work with the list i get from the parse of the pairs:

```
pair:: [(Maybe String, Maybe String)] -> [(Int, Int)]
pair [] = []
pair ((Just x, Just y) : ls) = (read x, read y) : pair ls
```

It works fine. But i tried to do the same for the list with the letters and it doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
letter :: [Maybe String] -> [Char]
letter [] = []
letter (Just x : ls) = read x : letter ls
```

When i run this, i get the list of pairs right and this error

```
myfile.hs: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Why is this happening? Is the read function the problem?

Comment: Slightly misquoting Cale from #haskell: "Beware of the function `Maybe a -> a`. For it may contain trappes and sprynges of great variety and harm."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your definition of letter to:

```
letter :: [Maybe String] -> [Char]
letter [] = []
letter (Just x : ls) = (head x) : letter ls
```

Explanation: `read` will try to read the content of string as an Haskell Char literal. Since Char literals in Haskell are terminated by quotes, your strings would need to include them (i.e: `read "'B'" :: Char` works, `read "B" :: Char` does not).

Answer (score 3):

The `read` parser for `Char` expects the character to be surrounded in single quotes, i.e. you need a string like `"'M'"`.

```
Prelude> read "M" :: Char
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
Prelude> read "'M'" :: Char
'M'
```

You probably want to do something like

```
letter :: [Maybe String] -> [Char]
letter [] = []
letter (Just [x] : ls) = x : letter ls
```

However, this of course only works if you always get just `Just` values and no `Nothing` values and all strings must have a length of one or the pattern match will fail.

Comment: What if the first element of the list is `Nothing`?

Comment: @DiegoNolan "However, this of course only works if you always get just `Just` values and no `Nothing` values." But I agree with you that this is a code smell.

Comment: This works as well. About the "nothing". In the function that i parse the letter, i put if the list is empty(the XML file i mean), it returns empty list. Will it return a "Nothing" in it in that case? I don't return "maybe string" because i want. I use functions that i import from "Text.XML.Light". I use the function findAttr and it gives me a Maybe String. I don't know what it does in a nothing situation but i imagine it returns empty too.

Comment: @PedroLino According to the type system [Just "ABC", Nothing, Just "C"] is valid input to this function.  Your program will die(pattern match exception kind of like head []) if that is the  case.  to fix it add a letter (Nothing :ls) = letter ls or add a default value in there whatever you want to have happen when you get a Nothing.